# clear textbox text before ajax form submit event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I want to clear textbox after ajax posting.

```
<div style="padding: 5px; background-color: Silver;">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = Model.room_id.ToString() }))
    {
        <div style="padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px;">
            @Html.TextBox("textbox_message", null, new { @class = "text_yorum", id = "text_box_chat" })
            @Html.Hidden("oda_id", Model.room_id)
        </div>
    }
</div>

<div id="@Model.room_id" style="height:400px;overflow-y:scroll;position: relative;">
    @Html.Action("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new { room_id = Model.room_id })
</div>
```

there are a lot of example, but they do not work.
I m already using this code, but it is too slow.

```
   $("form").submit(function () {
       $.get('@Url.Action("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new { room_id = Model.room_id }) ', {}, function (view) {
           $("#@Model.room_id").html(view);
           $("#text_box_chat").val("");
       });
   });
```

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about clearing the box before waiting for the response?

```
   $("form").submit(function () {
       setTimeout(function(){
         $("#text_box_chat").val("");
       }, 20);
       $.get('@Url.Action("_MessagesPartial", "Chat", new { room_id = Model.room_id }) ', {}, function (view) {
           $("#@Model.room_id").html(view);
       });
   });
```

Comment: if use this code. clear textbox before submitting. so submit empty textbox.

Comment: now working. thanks a lot. faster than my solution. i cant vote up. sorry :)